# Make all threads wait for a method to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I have currently two threads running in a main. In one of the threads I have a method that writes data to a file (.txt) (thread 1) and in the other thread I have method that reads data from the same file (thread 2). I wonder is there a way to when the read method in thread 2 is executing make the other thread wait with its execution until the read method in thread 2 finishes?

This is how it looks:
Thread 1:

Function that writes data to a file
want to wait here until Thread 2 read method finishes
writeTextToFile(text)

Thread 2:

method to read data from a file same file as thread 2 writes to
execute in peace without any other thread running until it finishes
readFile();

code below:

```
package parser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import utils.ReadMachine;
import utils.TextProcessor;
import utils.WriteMachine;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.Tokenizer;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.TokenizerFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.CoreLabelTokenFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;

public class Parser implements Runnable {

    private String parserModel;
    private LexicalizedParser lp;
    private ReadMachine rwm;
    private WriteMachine wm;
    private TextProcessor tp;
    private String from;
    private int nbr;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Parser.class);

    public Parser(String from, String to, int nbr) {
        rwm = new ReadMachine();
        this.nbr = nbr;
        this.from = from;
        this.parserModel = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";

        this.tp = new TextProcessor();
        this.wm = new WriteMachine(to);
    }

    public String parser(String toBeParsed) {

        Tree parse;

        if (toBeParsed == null) {
            toBeParsed = "This is a sentence.";
        }

        TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(
                new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
        Tokenizer<CoreLabel> tok = tokenizerFactory
                .getTokenizer(new StringReader(toBeParsed));
        List<CoreLabel> raw = tok.tokenize();

        parse = lp.apply(raw);

        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = lp.treebankLanguagePack(); // PennTreebankLanguagePack
                                                                // for English
        GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
        GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
        List<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();

        return tdl.toString();

    }

    private void parseFromTo() {
        ArrayList<String> proc = null;
        proc = rwm.readFile(from);
        if (proc != null && proc.size() > 0) {
            proc = tp.sentenceDivider(proc);
        }
        for (String line : proc) {
            logger.info(line);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        while (true) {
                WANT this method to execute in peace
                this.parseFromTo();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.info("Sleep interupted");
            }
        }
    }

}

package crawler;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.parser.HtmlParseData;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL;

public class Crawler extends WebCrawler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Crawler.class);
    public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    private int index;
    private static int indx = 0;

    private final static Pattern FILTERS = Pattern
            .compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g"
                    + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4"
                    + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf"
                    + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz|txt))$");
    private String[] patterns = { "[Mm][Ii][Gg]", "[Mm][Aa][Gg]",
            "[Gg][Mm][Aa][Ww]", "[Ww][Ee][Ll][Dd][Ii][Nn][Gg]" };

    private String path = "/Users/aloefqvi/Dropbox/1337_Haxor/LTH/courses/EDAN70/parse_files/from/text/"
            + "from" + Integer.toString(this.index = indx++) + ".txt";

    private Downloader dl = new Downloader(patterns, path);

    protected void setOs(OutputStream os) {

    }

    /**
     * You should implement this function to specify whether the given url
     * should be crawled or not (based on your crawling logic).
     */
    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
        String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
        return !FILTERS.matcher(href).matches();
    }


    @Override
    public void visit(Page page) {

        if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
            HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
            String text = htmlParseData.getText();
            Set<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();
            String urlData = "";
            for (WebURL item : links) {
                urlData = urlData + newline + item;
            }
                WANT this thread to wait here until parseToFile finishes
                dl.download(text.trim(), false);

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: That's basically what synchronization does. Read the Java concurrency tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet for pointing me in the right direction i fixed it

Comment: Is there a requirement that the threads communicate via a file, or would it be acceptable for them to communicate via messages or shared memory e.g. thread1 writes data to a file and sends the data it's just written to thread2 using a thread-safe queue?  This would be more efficient, as disk access is quite expesive

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [file locking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) do it for you.
But, to communicate between threads in a process, better methods exist.
See [Queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use a [Lock](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_9_locks_j5b.shtml) (specifically, usually a ReentrantLock). Essentially, you create a Lock object to administer access to the file. Then, before performing a read or write on the file, you call lock() -- which waits if the lock (and hence the file) is already in use by the other thread. Once a given thread is done reading/writing, it calls unlock() to free up the lock, which another waiting thread will then immediately acquire as applicable.

If appropriate for your application, you also have the option of a ReentrantReadWriteLock, which potentially allows multiple reads at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of synchronization will solve your issue but it will be great if you can 
change your approach and switch to latest java concurrency utilities ,from java 1.5 we have BlockingQueue available .
eg ->

- [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html]

Use the method take and offer and leave everything else to queue.